# Compare two list in java

Tags: java, arrays, list

I have two list :

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [2,3,4]
```

I want to take all the element of two list with no same value and each element will repeat once example :

```
list3 = [1,2,3,4]
```

`list3` will get element of `list1` and `list2`.

Comment: Do you have a question? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Loop through the 1st list and copy any value that is not in list2 into it.
Then sort the list.

Comment: add both `List`'s to a `Set` and you´re done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quick way is to use a Set for example :

**Input**

```
List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);

List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(2,3,4);
```

**Add your lists to Set**

```
Set<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>();
set.addAll(list1);        
set.addAll(list2);
```

**Output**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(Integer i : list2){
    if(!list1.contains(i)){
        list1.add(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the unique values from the 2nd list to the first one:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list2.size(); i++)
    if (!list1.contains(list2.get(i))
        list1.add(list2.get(i));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this properly with :

```
List<Integer> A = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
List<Integer> B = Arrays.asList(2,3,4);

List<Integer> D = ListUtils.subtract(B, A);// contain 4
```

**Output**

```
List<Integer> C = ListUtils.union(A, D); // 1,2,3,4
```